# How can I restrict tags that are able to be used?

Tags: entries, tags, admin

Just downloaded and am setting up Craft. Super excited! I would like to know the following:

At the moment, I am assigning tags to entries in the hopes of using them as an organizational/navigation tool at some point in the future. My question is, how—if at all—can I create a list of tags that can be used IN ADVANCE? In other words, restrict the possible tags that can be assigned to now and future entries?

So, the admin can only choose/use: "branding", "design", and "identity", for example. And not "copywriting." Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4):

That’s not possible, as tags are meant to be more of a “[folksonomy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Folksonomy)” rather than a strict taxonomy.

Sounds to me like [categories](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/categories) would be a better fit for your needs. With those, the options are defined in advance, and *chosen* from the fields, rather than *created* from the fields.

**Update:**

We just updated the [Categories and Tags](http://buildwithcraft.com/features/categories-and-tags) feature page with a new video that may do a better job showing the difference between the two.